# C# enter value into multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, datagridview

I am build a program with c#, and have included dataGridView on it. I do math operation on that dataGridView data, then insert the result into multidimensional array. But i got error message that say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

here my code:

1. frm_clustering.cs

   ```
   public void hitungMatriksJarak()
   {
       clusteringModel cm = new clusteringModel();

       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < this.dgv_clustering.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           for (j = 0; j < this.dgv_clustering.Rows.Count; j++)
           {
               cm.matriks[j,i] = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(this.dgv_clustering[1, i].Value), 2) +
                                            Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(this.dgv_clustering[2, i].Value), 2) +
                                            Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(this.dgv_clustering[3, i].Value), 2) +
                                            Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(this.dgv_clustering[4, i].Value), 2));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. clusteringModel.cs:

   ```
   class clusteringModel
   {
       private int _jmlKel;
       public int jmlKel
       {
           get { return _jmlKel; }
           set { _jmlKel = value; }
       }

       private double[,] _matriks = new double[500,500];
       public double[,] matriks
       {
           get { return _matriks; }
           set { _matriks = value; }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You create the first part of the array, but never create the second parts. You need to loop through the 500 first indicies of the array and create the second array for each.

Comment: The first comment is incorrect, you are creating a simple two dimensional array, not an array of arrays. The stack trace from your null reference exception should explain the problem. Or set a break point where the error is happening and see what's null, it's probably one of the values you're trying to pull out of dgv_clustering.